# Async fluent javascript (node) interface (using deferreds)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fluent-interface, deferred

What is the best way to build fluent interface in Javascript (node.js) with

```
obj.function1().function2().function3();
```

where functions are asynchronous methods?

There is a module called chainsaw, but if it is possilble to do with deferreds and promises  (https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

UPD: chain with q.js

```
obj.function1().then(obj.function2) 
//inside obj.function2 "this" context is lost, 
//and code is actually broken

obj.function1().then(funciton(){
  obj.function2() // <-- "this" context is OK
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deferred](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred#deferred--modular-and-fast-promises-implementation-for-javascript) implementation allows you to do something close, with `invoke`:

```
obj.function1().invoke('function2').invoke('function3');
```

When ES6 proxies will become a reality, there is a plan to allow same functionality with code below

```
obj.function1().function2().function3();
```

but we're not there yet.

Also worth noting is that in [Deferred](https://github.com/medikoo/deferred#deferred--modular-and-fast-promises-implementation-for-javascript) `promise` object is actually a function which equals to `promise.then`. So plain functions can be chained as:

```
function1()(function2)(function3);
```

I hope that's helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, well kind of. The chain would need to be differently constructed :

```
obj.function1().then(obj.function2).then(obj.function3);
```

- `function1` would need to return a resolved/resolvable promise.
- `function2` (or all intermediate functions) would need to return a result or a new resolved/resolvable promise.
- `function3` (or whichever function comes last) would need to do something with the accumulated result of the earlier functions in the chain - ie. it must be a "consumer" function.

As promises have a mechanism for rejection as well as resolution, a promise-chain offers greater inherent possibilities than chainsaw, to allow/terminate progress down the chain.

As the promise interface includes methods other than `.then()`, further flexibility is also provided.

That said, I've not looked at *chainsaw* before, so I've not really got my mind round its full potential.

Comment: Thanks but, I understand that with promises I can easily make chain like obj.function1().then(obj.function2), but I'm more interested in fluent chain.

Comment: The short answer is that promises only expose promise methods and that these methods dictate chain syntax.

Comment: It seems that when I call .then(obj.function2) while function2 executing "this context" is lost ("this" does not refer to obj)

Comment: Look at update of my question. Not to loose context chain becomes even more ugly.

Comment: I fear you are right. The functions become detached so you need to take defensive measures to prevent loss of context. For example, assign `var self = this`, and work with `self`, as in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CphSX/) (jQuery not Q, though the principle is the same).